# Are the rest of the terms of this sequence o? 77, 49, 36, 18, 8, ...

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a homework assignment that asks for the next three terms of a bunch of sequences, etc.

So there's this one sequence I finally figured out. I was given: 77, 49, 36, 18...
I realized that the first digit times the second was the next term. After 18, the term would be 8. After 8, are the rest of the terms o's?

Comment: After 8, al the terms of the sequence are 42. (Say, which curriculum asks you this type of "exercise"? Not a mathematical one, I hope?)

Comment: @Did Where did you get 42 from? Also, I'm recapping on series and sequences in  Pre-Calc. rn...

Comment: @C.Guan $42$ could be any other value. The point is that there are infinitely many sequences starting with $77,49, 36, 18, 8$, and that pretending that one can find the rest of the terms without adding very strong rules or assumptions is meaningless. $(77,49, 36, 18, 8, 42,42,42,42,42,42,42,\dots, 42,\dots)$ is a perfectly valid sequence; so is $(77,49, 36, 18, 8, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\dots)$. Why shouldn't they be good answers?

Comment: @ClementC. I think I forgot to mention that there must be a pattern. Or at least you should just assume it...

Comment: What better pattern than in 77,49,36,18,8,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,…,42,… ?

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two reasonable possibilities, and I see no way to choose one. One is that each term is the product of the digits of the preceding term when that is written without leading zeroes; in that case each term after $18$ is $8$. Another is that each term is the product of the last two digits of the preceding term, written with a leading zero if necessary so that it has at least two digits; in that case every term after $18$ is indeed $0$.

By discovering that each term so far is the product of the digits of the preceding term, you have in my opinion solved the problem; if I were writing it up as homeword, I’d explain the ambiguity and offer both of the possibilities in the first paragraph.

Comment: @C.Guan: You’re welcome!